# Recommendations are not appearing in Einstein Replies component

Tags: einstein, einstein-recommendations, einstein-chatbot

I have recently setup Einstein Reply Recommendations in one of our sandboxes. The sandbox has enough chat transcripts and I have enabled it with 10 Quick Texts.
The Quick Texts are stored in a folder which is created by me, hence having the Manage permission.
I am able to see "Einstein Replies" component on the chat transcript page. However, at the time of chat I am not seeing any recommendations even if I use keywords of the quick texts that I have enabled.
Could anyone suggest what is left behind or what could be wrong with the setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the user with these two permissions:

1. Permission to create quick text
2. Manage Replies for Einstein Reply Recommendations user permission